# Equivalent of the Kirsch Equations for an elliptical rather than circular hole

Tags: stress-strain

Is there an equivalent set of closed form equations to the [Kirsch Equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirsch_equations) but for an elliptical hole rather than a circular hole?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inglis used complex potential functions to extend Kirsch's work to treat the stress field around a plate containing an elliptical rather than circular hole

http://www.saylor.org/site/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/ME1023.2.1.pdf